# org.gnome.SessionManager in Ubuntu 12.04 chroot

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dbus, chroot, gnome-3, totem

I'm trying to test totem in a minimal chroot (host and chroot both ubuntu 12.04 amd64).  When I load a video, I get the error

```
** (totem:25660): WARNING **: Problem inhibiting the screensaver: GDBus.Error:
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.SessionManager" does not exist
```

Indeed, the screen will turn off (session idle) while watching a video.  To confirm, I tested with python:

```
>>> import dbus
>>> bus = dbus.SessionBus()
>>> bus.get_object('org.gnome.SessionManager','/org/gnome/SessionManager')
```

and get the error

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name
org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Does anyone know what packages would provide the dbus interface org.gnome.SessionManager in a chroot?  After searching on this, I've tried gnome-session, gnome-session-common and gnome-session-bin to no avail.

By searching on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) and on a full 12.04 system where these both work correctly, there doesn't appear to be any package providing a file named org.gnome.SessionManager.service, so what .service file is it looking for?.

Answer (score 0):

On a system where that service is working, you can find out by querying the bus like this:

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.GetNameOwner org.kde.klipper
:1.82
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.DBus / org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID :1.82
1441
$ readlink /proc/1441/exe
/usr/bin/kdeinit4
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/kdeinit4           # in your case dpkg -S /path/to/program
kdelibs4-4.7.2-5.5.1.x86_64
```

Comment: These steps worked exactly as you said.   However, they led back to the executable `/usr/bin/gnome-session`, which is in the package `gnome-session-bin`. This seems like the right answer, but as I noted before, for some reason the gnome-session packages alone didn't do it.