# Changing xscreensaver to gnome-screensaver

Tags: lockscreen, screensaver, xfce

I'm using openSUSE 13.1 with Xfce 4.10. I'd like to make a lock screen more pretty. I read that I can remove xscreensaver and install gnome-screensaver instead and I did it. When I try to run it (using command `gnome-screensaver`) then I get message `** (gnome-screensaver:2208): WARNING **: Couldn't get presence status: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files`. And I stucked here.

**Question**: What to do to go further or how can I make the lock screen more pretty?

Comment: Try installing the gnome-session package. Could be relative to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171384/org-gnome-sessionmanager-in-ubuntu-12-04-chroot